# ContactListener not registering all contacts when attacking enemy - Box2d platformer

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

My character is a knight that attacks with a sword, so I figured that the following would be the easiest way of making the attack collisions: when the player presses attack button, character swings his sword and a new fixture/body is created for the swing (a rectangle in front of the player). This is the class with the sword attack body:

```
public class SwordCut {

    private final GameScreen screen;
    private final World world;

    private Body b2body;

    protected Fixture fixture;

    public SwordCut(GameScreen screen) {

        this.screen = screen;
        this.world = screen.getWorld();
    }

    public void defineBody(float cutX, float cutY) {
        BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        bdef.position.set(cutX, cutY);
        bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        b2body = world.createBody(bdef);
        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(36f / 2f / Constants.PPM, 40f / 2 / Constants.PPM);
        fdef.filter.categoryBits = Constants.ATTACK_COLLISION;
        fdef.filter.maskBits =
                Constants.ENEMY_BIT;
        fdef.shape = shape;
        fixture = b2body.createFixture(fdef);
        fixture.setSensor(true);
        fixture.setUserData(true);
    }

    public void destroyBody() {
        world.destroyBody(b2body);
    }

    public Body getBody() {
        return b2body;
    }
}
```

In the contact listener I made the enemy lose health when a contact between the enemy and the sword begins.

```
@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

    int cDef = fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits;


    switch (cDef) {
...
case Constants.ATTACK_COLLISION | Constants.ENEMY_BIT:
            if (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits == Constants.ENEMY_BIT) {
                ((Monster) fixA.getUserData()).loseHealth(10);
                Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Enemy hit");
            }
            else {
                ((Monster) fixB.getUserData()).loseHealth(10);
                Gdx.app.debug(TAG, "Enemy hit");
            }
            break;
```

However, not all hits are being registered, and when I hit the enemy several times when it's not working, sometimes bumping into the enemy with the player makes the enemy lose the health for all the previous attacks at once (so it's like all the previous hits are being registered only after touching the enemy). Sometimes it's working, sometimes not, I haven't noticed any particular reason or pattern.

[image]